# php mysql insert image BLOB field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, blob, image-upload

i had a table with 6 fields `students_id, customer_id, firstname, lastname, image_name, image` this `image` field is BLOB type, `image_name` field image filename and extension. i know how to get stored image from blob field and display to my webpage, i tested it with uploading image via phpmyadmin... my question is how can i store image in my `image` field.?

this is what i use for my other fields..

```
<?php
public function addStudents($data) {
     $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "students SET customer_id = '" .
 (int)$this->customer->getId() . "', firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) .
 "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "'");
}
?>
```

its my HTML image upload section

```
<input type="file" name="image" />
```

anyone please help me? if anyone can answer with edit my source code its very helpful...

thanks...

Comment: storing images in the database is a BAD idea. it may seem handy now, but you'll be ripping out hair later on. DON'T DO IT. store the images somewhere on the server's file system, and simply store the path to the file in the db.

Comment: @MarcB, can you elaborate on the 'hair ripping' issues that may arise?  I've always steered toward using the filesystem primarily because of storage and backup concerns.  But what issues are there programmatically?

Comment: So, you aren't actually asking anything about databases or BLOBs, are you? Your question is about [handling file uploads in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)?

Comment: @pinny: having to query the file everytime it's requested, the bandwidth bill that comes in when you find out your images weren't being cached by the various client browsers (or whatever) because they weren't served up in the "normal" method. vastly bloated database dumps because of the tons of unless binary garbage in them.

Comment: @MarcB, depending on how your routing and cache control is performed, caching shouldn't really be an issue should it?  I concur that db dumps will get out of hand fairly quickly though...

Comment: ofcourse its all about uploading image to blob field, what code i add with my above code.?

Comment: @PinnyM people that know enough to set `cache-control` and `content-expiry` headers when they serve images out of a database are the ones that know not to serve images out of a database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/, it is clearly explained

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.